# Submit field without completing "hidden" mandatory fields unless they are selected

Tags: javascript, forms, webforms, adobe, business-catalyst

I have a Member Registration Form where by Payment Details are required ONLY when a certain selection is made.

If I am a Member and just wanting to register myself, it won't cost me anything so no payment is required. In this instance, I want to be able to submit the form without completing the Payment Details as they are hidden from me any way using some javascript I had someone help me with.

If however, I want to bring a guest or two with me, I can select Member + XX Guests. Only when additional guests are selected do I want the Payment Options to appear and be processed.

You can see the page I am working on here: http://www.faa.net.au/test/femmes-member-form.html

Any idea how I can do this? Any help is appreciated.

This is using Adobe Business Catalyst, even though I have tagged those words, just in case it wasnt clear. THANKS.

Comment: Use `if` statements to see if something is selected. By the way, remember to **always** validate the same input on the server - you can't rely on the client/JavaScript

Comment: @Ian How would I do this using Adobe Business Catalyst?

Comment: Where exactly are the payment options that are hidden from the user? You're using jquery so you can find out what the user has selected by doing `.find(':selected')` so check if they have selected additional guests.

Comment: @aug If you select the Number of Tickets dropdown you will see the first option is Member Only and then Member + 1 Guest, etc. When you add select a Guest, the Payment Options appears. Please refer to my link above for the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your validation is being done in this function of the HTML:

```
function checkWholeForm65983(theForm) {
var why = "";
if (theForm.FirstName) why += isEmpty(theForm.FirstName.value, "First Name");
if (theForm.LastName) why += isEmpty(theForm.LastName.value, "Last Name");
if (theForm.EmailAddress) why += checkEmail(theForm.EmailAddress.value);
if (theForm.HomePhone) why += isEmpty(theForm.HomePhone.value, "Home Phone Number");
if (theForm.CaptchaV2) why += captchaIsInvalid(theForm, "Enter Word Verification in box below", "Please enter the correct Word Verification as seen in the image");
if (theForm.CAT_Custom_257593) why += isEmpty(theForm.CAT_Custom_257593.value, "Member Number");
if (theForm.CAT_Custom_255275) why += checkDropdown(theForm.CAT_Custom_255275.value, "Available Dates");
if (theForm.CAT_Custom_255276 ) why += checkDropdown(theForm.CAT_Custom_255276.value, "Number of Tickets");
if (theForm.CAT_Custom_255277) why += checkSelected(theForm.CAT_Custom_255277, "Payment Method");
if (theForm.CAT_Custom_255279) why += isEmpty(theForm.CAT_Custom_255279.value, "Questions / Message or Other Information");
if (why != "") {
    alert(why);
    return false;
}
if (submitcount65983 == 0) {
    submitcount65983++;
    theForm.submit();
    return false;
} else {
    alert("Form submission is in progress.");
    return false;
}
}
```

Specifically `CAT_Custom_255277` is what is double checking that Payment Options are being filled. We want to ignore this check if `Member = $0` is selected though. So try something like this:

```
if (theForm.CAT_Custom_255277 && theForm.CAT_Custom_255276.value != "1") 
    why += checkSelected(theForm.CAT_Custom_255277, "Payment Method");
```

The reason we set it to `"1"` is because your option for `Member = $0` is set to `"1"`:

```
<option value="1">Member = $0</option>
```

Hope this works!